# Show that $B_1(0)$ is a closed set in the space $C([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, fake-proofs, sequence-of-function

> Let be $(C([0,1]),\Vert \cdot\Vert_{\infty})$ the normed space of continuous functions, equipped with the supremum norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$.
>
> Show that $B_1(0):=\{f\in C([0,1])\mid\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}\leq 1\}$ is a closed set.

Let be $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a convergent sequence (of functions) and $f$ its limit (function). Then, for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ we find an $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>n_0$ we have that

$$\begin{align*}
&\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}-\Vert f_n\Vert_{\infty}\leq \Vert f-f_n\Vert_{\infty}<\epsilon\\
&\implies \Vert f\Vert_{\infty}<\epsilon+\Vert f_n\Vert_{\infty}\leq\epsilon+1.
\end{align*}$$
As $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary it must be $\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}\leq 1$ because otherwise $\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$ was not the smallest upper bound. Hence, $f\in B_1(0)$.

---

I was 100% sure that this is correct but my tutor left a comment that I can't do it this way and that I should review the sample solution. Where is my mistake?

Comment: First and foremost before even coming here, did you at least consider consulting your tutor and having them elaborate? We can only conjecture what they might have meant, regardless of how obvious it might be (I haven't looked at it in detail yet, but it seems there is a simple solution to your real problem here).

Comment: Your definition of $B_1(0)$ looks wrong. Perhaps you mean ":" where you have "$\in$"?

Comment: @PrincessEev, Yes I did consider it and she didn't reply.

Comment: @RobArthan, it was a typo

Comment: I don't see any error in your proof.

Comment: Maybe your tutor wanted you to justify why $f$ is continuous.